# pdf download link in ipad app not working

Tags: ipad, pdf

i have a standalone offline html application which is not meant for deployment on a server.
i have converted that html application into an ipad app.

The application has links to local pdf and excel files. I have provided links to download those file in the application. It works fine in browser.

But in ipad the links to download pdf report and excel sheet reports do not work (even if I tap on the links pdf doesn't show up.It behaves like a dead link!)

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

For downloading pdf try following:

1) Create one button to call `printTapped()` method
   (UIBarButtonItem is good for this here)

**printTapped()**

```
- (void)printTapped 
{  


    NSData *pdfdata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:@"try your url from where you want to download the pdf"];

    //Store the Data locally as PDF File

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *docsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",app.stritreejob]];

      //=======//
}
```

Comment: this is objective c code. which i have no idea about. is there any solution for this into html or javascript.